# Determine next auto increment value on a grouped AUTO_INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, create-table, grouped-table

I have beneath TABLE and it's working fine when adding a record

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `certificates` (    
  `certyearmonth` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    
  `certmonthnumber` mediumint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
  `stockid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
  `checklisttemplateid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,    
  `certificateid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`certyearmonth`,`certmonthnumber`),    
  KEY `checklisttemplateid` (`checklisttemplateid`),    
  KEY `certificateid` (`certificateid`)    
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When adding a record the certmonthnumber is counting+1 within the same certyearmonth.

```
201310    1
201310    2
201310    3
201311    1
201311    1
```

How can I determine the next auto_increment on a specific certyearmonth value? 
Example: How can I determine the next value for certmonthnumber when certyearmonth==201310,
or when certyearmonth==201401?

Comment: Whyever would you want to?

Comment: The two columns together are the unique code for this Certificate. I want to show it on screen and mail it to the QA group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` to find the current highest value, then add 1 to that value. Use `COALESCE()` to handle the case of certyearmonth values that are not yet present in the table, and you can solve both of your examples with the same query:

```
mysql> select coalesce(max(certmonthnumber),0)+1 as next_val
    -> from certificates 
    -> where certyearmonth = '201310';
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select coalesce(max(certmonthnumber),0)+1 as next_val
    -> from certificates 
    -> where certyearmonth = '201410';
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This needs a huge big **WARNING** attached to it, that the results cannot be relied upon to be meaningful (since another session may insert a new record before the results are used).

Comment: @eggyal that is true.

Comment: You are right.... is there a way to get a 'reservation' or something like that?  A lock on the next auto_increment?

Comment: @RemcoAngioni: Insert a record, obtain its ID, then update as & when.